# How do I preserve the code's color when I ask in a webpage's board?

Tags: discussion

When I ask question about java code ,

I copy the code in eclipse. And then I paste the code on the web board like here.

But the code's color become black only. Red, blue colors are not showing.

How do I preserve the code's color when I write down the code on web?

Comment: Could you link to the question that hasn't highlighted correctly?

Answer (score 4):

If you include an appropriate language tag ([java] in this case) and indent your code properly (using the {} button) it will be automatically highlighted correctly

Comment: It is important to note that the preview does not show the syntax highlighting,  It doesn't appear until the question (or answer) is actually posted.

Comment: nope @psubsee2003: The preview does show the syntax highlighting If you wait for few seconds (4-5?).

Comment: @hims056 only when editing, not when you ask new question. I just verified this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Sha - If the language hint is given then we can see while asking too. And answer preview shows even without language hint while answering.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was sure there was a feature request for that somewhere, can't seem to find it though

Comment: @hims056 true but keep in mind we can't expect new users who just post a question to know that or to add language hints... adding proper tag is enough and they should just know highlight will work based on the tag. Anyway, we're spamming poor Richard here. :-)

Comment: @RichardTingle right, can't find it either. Good chance it never got any upvotes or upvoted answers, so got auto deleted at some point. I remember shog (or other CM) mention there are hundreds of such auto deleted feature requests and bug reports. :(